# MySQL, Remote connection and security

Tags: mysql, security, amazon-web-services, ssl

By default, when you open the `bind-address` to listen to the outside, the default communication between the MySQL client & server is not secured, that means anyone that can do a MitM attack can view every transactions made.

There is options out there to protect against this type of attack (SSH Tunneling or enabling SSL in MySQL) but from what I understand, Amazon RDS doesn't implement, [by default](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), any SSL security.

So I'm wondering, when you create an RDS instance, is it like installing MySQL on a server and opening the 3306 port or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

A few points.  Firstly AWS RDS for mysql does support ssl.  This is discussed here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

Second, the usual way to arrange servers in a AWS VPC is to have "private" and "public" subnets.  The private subnets route to other private hosts and perhaps to other hosts in the same VPC.  But they have no Elastic IPs and no direct access to the Internet Gateway.  It is usual to put databases on private subnets so that their ports are not exposed

There is a nice diagram on this page showing this concept

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html

Lastly, AWS RDS exists within the philosphy of [the shared responsiblity model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/)

This tries to make it clear what security AWS services provide and what is supposed to be the responsibility of the customer

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating an instance you've to also allow port 3306 to be open at your endpoints. This means you've to also configure your security settings as to which IP you've to allow for this connection. Regarding SSL security or SSH, as a good practice you should rely on ssh keys with Pass phrase.